# my camera track stops tracking before reaching the last frame of my video

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes, tracking

I am trying to track found footage of a drone shot, the camera movement is very smooth. My pattern size is 40, my search size is 100. The track stops tracking around 3/4 of the way through the clip, the blue/red "track line" dissapears, indicitve that its not tracking anymore. Is there anyway to get it to continue to track? I tried to reposition it and clicked the track forward button but this did not work. I also tried using the refine button but this did not work either. I attached a photo of this frame, where it "falls off" and stops tracking.  [image]